# ember-data async hasMany requests

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model that looks like:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ordernumber: DS.attr('string'),
  allowMeasurementsFrom: DS.attr('date'),
  devices: DS.hasMany('device', { async: true })
});
```

And when I do a request to a page that is about one order I get these requests:

```
GET "http://localhost:51799/devices/0fd27d12-fd25-412d-bcf6-6e84064bd951".
GET "http://localhost:51799/devices/a84142bd-b314-4e6e-a29f-6821fb7f32fb".
GET "http://localhost:51799/devices/3b1ed530-1cf6-42fb-90b7-f1d4886dce05".
```

But I expected a request with multiple ids, like it says in the docs [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships). Like:

```
GET "http://localhost:51799/devices?ids[]=3b1ed530-1cf6-42fb-90b7-f1d4886dce05&ids[]=a84142bd-b314-4e6e-a29f-6821fb7f32fb&ids[]=3b1ed530-1cf6-42fb-90b7-f1d4886dce05".
```

And this is my template:

```
{{id}}

{{#each dev in devices}}
  <img {{bind-attr src=dev.image}}>
  {{dev.deviceId}}
{{/each}}
```

I've tried looping through the devices directly and getting them in the controller first and then, looping through the devices. In both cases it does `n` requests.

I'm using the `DS.RESTAdapter`. Versions: Ember: 1.10.0 Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.15

Comment: Are you accessing the `devices` in a template, or by using `order.get('devices')`?

Comment: From a template in a ``{{#each}}`` but I also tried `{{devices}}` but that just prints something like `DS.PromiseArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information I had was a bit out of date. Luckily the information you need is fairly reasonably documented. You want the [`coalesceFindRequests` property](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_coalesceFindRequests). Set that to `true` in your adapter and it should coalesce them like you see in the guide. If you haven't overridden the adapter yet, you can do so by creating a `adapters/application.js` file that looks like this:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    coalesceFindRequests: true
});
```

Comment: I was a bit premature in accepting this answer :). I've updated the question.

Comment: Why do you think this isn't the default behaviour?

Comment: Probably for backwards compatibility. It's a fairly new feature and the Ember team doesn't like breaking changes.